# my.cnf couldn't be written - Dropbox - Mamp Pro 2.2 - Mavericks

Tags: permissions, dropbox, osx-mavericks, my.cnf, mamp-pro

I am using a project in MAMP Pro in an upgraded installation; I developed it in an old version, now I'm using it in the current version.

Two years ago, I had shared the db to dropbox, that's worked perfectly with my db path pointing to the same direction; /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db

The db is in the mamp folder & the folder is in my dropbox.

But when I make changes and I start sql server with mamp pro, I get an error saying; "my.cnf couldn't be written" and the server doesn't start.

If I undo my changes and put the db in "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db" and I restart the app, the server runs properly.

I tried solution I came across on the web changing the properties using CHMOD on dropbox, restarting the computer, uninstall mamp pro and reinstall, etc...

Someone have solution ? 
Special chmod user on dropbox ? 
I have nothing in log of MAMP PRO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem... I'm using alias and not symbolic link...
Now all is fine...

So if someone make the same thing, don't use "alias" option from Mavericks but make real symbolic link.